# Best practice for using perfect scroll in every block content in angular 7

Tags: angular, scrollbar

I usually use the perfect scroll for some block even when I work with Angular. However, I'm not sure if it's a wise solution when applying for every block that has scrollbar in Angular 7. Anyone has a better idea for my case?

Answer (score 0):

Note: ich have no experience with perfect-scrollbar

After a quick research i found "ngx-perfect-scrollbar" (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-perfect-scrollbar).

I think it is a good option if there are no significant performance problems.